# C Finding Maximum and Minimum value?

Tags: c, arrays

In Case of Finding Maximum and minimum Value in Array.  We intialize `max =0` or `max=temp[0];`
But in case of Minimum value we doesn't require to initialize `min =0` or `min=temp[0]`...  Why?

Comment: Well initializing `min = 0` probably isn't very helpful...

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't initialize `max` with `0` in any case (for example, when finding maximum of array which contains all negative values if you initialize `max` with `0`, result will always be `0`).

Since for finding maximum (and minimum) you need to compare variable `max` (or `min`) with some other value, you need to initialize to `temp[0]` in any case to avoid comparing array elements with uninitialized variable.

I found the part of your code in another comment:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main() {
  int arr[3]; 
  int i,max,min; max=min=0;

  printf("Enter the value in Array \n"); 

  for(i=1;i<=3;i++) { 
     scanf("%d",&arr[i]); 
  }

  printf("\n Value of array \n"); 
  for(i=1;i<=3;i++) { printf("%d \n",arr[i]); } 

  printf("\n Finding Maximum and minimum value \n"); 

  for(i=1;i<=3;i++) { 
    if(arr[i]>max) max=arr[i]; 
    if(arr[i]<min) min=arr[i]; 
  }
  printf("Max = %d \n Min = %d \n ",max,min);
  getch(); 
}
```

There are few things that doesn't work:

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
```

In C, indexing starts from 0, so the valid array elements are `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`, so that for loop should be

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

Ok, now imagine that you have in your array elements 10, 5 and 7.

You're setting min value to 0:

```
max=min=0;
```

And now you are iterating over this loop:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++) { 
    //...  
    if(arr[i]<min) min=arr[i]; 
  }
```

Is `10 < 0`? No, it's not.

Is `5 < 0`? No, it's not.

Is `7 < 0`? No, it's not.

So you see, the min will never change.

To avoid this, just set it to the first element **after** reading the array:

```
   for(i= 0;i < 3;i++) { 
      scanf("%d",&arr[i]); 
   }
   min = max = arr[0];
```

Now, let's repeat our loop:

```
 for(i=0;i<3;i++) { 
    //...  
    if(arr[i]<min) min=arr[i]; 
  }
```

Is `10 < 10`? No, it's not.

Is `5 < 10`? Yes, it is! Set the min to the 5

Is `7 < 5`? No, it's not.

Now the `min` is 5.

Same issue you have in your existing code with max. Imagine you enter `-4`, `-55` and `-20` for elements - `max` would always stay `0`.

Comment: "I did it. i intialize max =0 and max[0] both are working properly..
but i do the same thing it not working....

Comment: @Manojrawat then please show us how you did it - include the sample of the code in the question.

Comment: @Manojrawat Ok, found the code in the comment, please see the updated post.

Answer (score 1):

**You always need to initialise variables in C before accessing them; it's undefined behaviour not to**. The best thing to do, is, having checked the array length is not zero, is to initialise `min` / `max` to the zeroth element. Then loop from the first element.

Comment: It's only undefined behaviour to *access* the value of an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @Ol Charlesworth; good point - +1 - and I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`max = temp[0]` acts as reference point. You start comparing each element with this and if any element is greater than this, `max` value will be updated to that one. similarly `min = temp[0]` is also valid, but now algorithm will be changed and you need to compare each element if anyone is smaller than this if yes then `min` will be updated to that.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
int arr[3];
int i,max,min;
max=min=0;

clrscr();
printf("Enter the value in Array \n");
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}

printf("\n Value of array \n");
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
printf("%d \n",arr[i]);
}
printf("\n Finding Maximum and minimum value \n");

for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
if(arr[i]>max)
max=arr[i];
if(arr[i]<min)
min=arr[i];
}
printf("Max = %d \n Min = %d \n ",max,min);
getch();
}

pls check this one.. if i'll initialize min=0 it;s not working...

Comment: @Manojrawat List of issues (1) there is nothing like `void main` in standard it is `int main`. (2)You are accessing out of bound.An array of three elements will have its values at 0th 1st and 2nd position only.Your all loop are running from 1 to 3 means a[3] is actually fourth position. (3) Initialize `max` and `min` with first element of array rather than zero. There should be something less than zero to work your `if` condition.